# Informix 11.5 SQL Select Carriage Return and Line Feed

Tags: sql, informix, carriage-return, linefeed

Informix 11.5

I am trying to search for carriage returns and line feeds that may exist in a VARCHAR field. First, I need a SELECT statement to show that they exist. Second, I need to REPLACE them with a space or other character.
I've tried all kinds of variations:

```
CHR(10) + CHR(13)

CHR(10) || CHR(13)

CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

CHAR(13) || CHAR(10)

SELECT CHR(10) from systables;
```

Everything gives an error: `Routine (chr) can not be resolved.`

I've been searching all over and just can't find anything that works, and I'm sure this is crazy stupid easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Get the ASCII package from the IIUG

The `CHR()` function was added to IDS 11.70; it isn't in IDS 11.50.

The good news is you can add the function because IDS is an extensible server.  The better news for you is that you can obtain the relevant code from the [IIUG web site](http://www.iiug.org/) in the [Software Archive](http://www.iiug.org/software) under the [Miscellaneous](http://members.iiug.org/software/index_MISC.html) section as [`ascii`](ftp://ftp.iiug.org/pub/informix/pub/ascii-20161018.234426.tar.gz).

That should allow you to do what you need.  (Note: I wrote the code way back when — before there was support built into any of the servers.)

#### Windows makes things more complicated

> I was uploading the `ascii.unl` file and I get an error that the number of columns do not match on line 13. Have you seen this before? I'm on Windows 2008. The errors are:
>
> - `846: Number of values in load file is not equal to number of columns.`
> - `847: Error in load file line 13.`

I hadn't seen it before, but I've not tried the file on Windows and … well, let's say life gets trickier on Windows than it is on Unix (and this bit isn't all that simple on Unix).

First of all, the data file needs to have CRLF line endings instead of the NL-only line endings that are standard on Unix.  (Note that NL, newline, is another name for LF, line feed — aka `'\n'`.)  For most lines in the unload file, that isn't a problem.

The two entries for which it might be (is) a problem are for CR and LF — entries 13 and 10 respectively.  In theory, if the entry for line 10 contains (in C string notation) `"10|\\\n\r\n"` (that is, 10, pipe, backslash, newline, CRLF), all should be OK; the absence of an error message for line 10 suggests that it is OK.

Similarly, the entry for line 13 is `"13|\r\r\n"`, which apparently causes grief.  The simplest trial fix is to add a backslash here too: `"13|\\\r\r\nn"`.  The backslash says "the next character doesn't have a special meaning".  If that doesn't work, we'll probably have to try hex-escape notation: `"13|\\0d\r\n"` — and use `dbaccess -X` to enable the hex escape notation.

With luck, one of those two (or both) will work.  If neither works, come back and we'll try to think of something else.

Comment: Wow, thank you Jonathan, you even pointed me right to the download! And looking into the files and the SQLCMD it looks like you actually wrote these! Very nice sir. Question: I was uploading the ascii.unl file and I get an error that the number of columns do not match on line 13. Have you seen this before? I'm on Windows 2008. 846: Number of values in load file is not equal to number of columns.
  847: Error in load file line 13.

Comment: I tried placing a '\' at line 13: "13|\"  but it still errored. I deleted the line for 13 and got all of the rest to load. I created a new .unl file with just this line: `13|\\0d\r\n` I ran dbaccess -X and it returned this error: `268: Unique constraint (informix.u2_ascii) violated.   100: ISAM error:  du
 847: Error in load file line 1.`

Comment: Grumble...ouch!  The line needs to contain the `13|\0d` followed by the CRLF line ending (6 ASCII characters plus a Windows line ending).  That's what the C notation showed — or, rather, was intended to show.  If that is what you tried, then I'm going to have to think hard.  If that isn't what you tried, please can you try it (along with `dbaccess -X`, of course)?  You may need to look at the table to see whether there's a row with 13 as the `val`.  If there is, then check to see what the `chr` column contains, if you can. But you may need to delete the row: `DELETE FROM ASCII WHERE val = 13;`

Comment: I just copied the `13|\\0d\r\n` from here into a new file, went into dbaccess -X and loaded the file. I just tried another new file with `13|\\\r\r\nn` and run it under normal dbaccess and also got the `Unique constraint` error. But, if you notice, the constraint is on u2 which is the 'chr' field not the val '13'. It seems to think that the line feed value is already in there under a different number? I'm not sure how to try and search for it inside the database? I tried `select * from ascii where chr like '%0d\r\n'` and the like but I don't think it recognizes the C string (which makes sense)

Comment: It's a reasonable bet that the entry for `val` equal to 10 is the culprit.  It's just a confounded nuisance that these are the two values you're actually interested in!  Do you have a technical support contract with IBM for this version of Informix?  If so, now might be a good time to use it.  Do you have ESQL/C (ClientSDK) and a C compiler on the machine?  Do you have JDBC and a Java compiler?  It may be simplest to deal with these two entries via a (small) program.  In essence: `DELETE FROM ASCII WHERE val IN (10, 13); INSERT INTO ASCII VALUES(10, '\n'); INSERT INTO ASCII VALUES(13, '\r');`.

Comment: Of course, there'd be a connection to establish, and we'd need to be confident that that the compiler has converted those `\n` and `\r` sequences into actual characters, and we might need to futz with placeholder variables to avoid futzing with `ifx_allow_newline()` and … it isn't quite as straight-forward as it might seem at first sight, but the general concept is simple enough and understandable.

Comment: I just wanted to update, that I submitted this to IBM on 1/23/17. As of 2/14/17 they have not figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my above comment:
I was uploading the ascii.unl file and I get an error that the number of columns do not match on line 13. Have you seen this before? I'm on Windows 2008. 846: Number of values in load file is not equal to number of columns. 847: Error in load file line 13.

Here is what I see in the ascii.unl file.

[image: ascii.unl]

If I put this into MS Word and turn on Show Formatting/Paragraph marks, it shows this:

[image]

[image]